# Create RDF data using PHP/EasyRdf and Store it on BlazeGraph

Tags: rdf, blazegraph, easyrdf

I want to store the rdf data that i have created using Easy/Rdf lib from php,
i used this :

```
$store = new \EasyRdf\GraphStore('http://192.168.1.35:9999/blazegraph/');
$store->replace($graph);
```

but it gives me an error :

> HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL

how can i do to properly create and store rdf data ?

Answer (score 0):

Graph stores are typically interacted with at their SPARQL endpoint. For blazegraph this will be at `http://192.168.1.35:9999/blazegraph/sparql`. This is why Blazegraph is complaining about not supporting requests to the URL you're sending them to.

You should be able to use the `GraphStore` class to insert the data; an alternative is to use EasyRdf's SparqlClient to insert data at the SPARQL endpoint. There's an example [here](https://github.com/easyrdf/easyrdf/blob/1.1.1/examples/basic_sparql.php) on this approach.